# How to make a home button in HTML with CSS?

Tags: button

I think this question is a silly one, but we are here for help, right? So can anyone tell me how to make a home button? Like Youtube, Facebook, W3schools or whatever? You can see Youtube example. And how to make it more beautiful with css?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ooIb.jpg) I was making this home button like this:

## Home

Without using CSS for now. I will write my real site's name instead of "home" in my html document.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use bootstrap, they have a lot of beautiful buttons and you can copy the source code and learn with it.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: thank you. by the way, I'm learning css now, and should I know css 100% to learn bootstrap?

Comment: You don't have to. If you know the basics you can start on bootstrap. It actually helps you improve your CSS